# JQUERY: Find images and wrap in li and link

Tags: jquery

Could anybody help me with some Jquery. I have a `<div>` with a bunch of images inside. I need to grab all the images, empty the `<div>`, wrap each image in an anchor with the image's `src` as the `href` and then wrap the link in a `<li>`.

This is what I have so far:

```
    var b = $('#thumbs .thumbs'); // Get a reference to the banner div
    var i = b.find('img'); // Pull all the images
    var s = i.attr('src');
    b.empty().append(i); // Empty the banner div, and replace the images
    b.find('img').wrap('<li><a href=" 'src' " /></li>'); // Wrap the images
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: It's ok I've worked it out: `var b = $('#thumbs .thumbs'); // Get a reference to the banner div
 var i = b.find('img'); // Pull all the images
 var src = i.attr('src');
 b.empty().append(i); // Empty the banner div, and replace the images
 b.find('img').wrap('<li><a href="' + src + '" /></li>'); // Wrap the images`

Comment: Post you own answer and accept it then. Code in comments is not really readable.

Comment: I still need help actually. What I posted does work, but I have multiple divs on the page with different image in them, and it is now grabbing all of them and putting them in the same div. Can I do this for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you are having images with in a div element like this

```
<div id="thumbs">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
    <img src="image.jpg" />
    <img src="image.jpg" />
    <ul></ul> 
</div>
```

Then you can use the following jquery function to do, what u expected

```
$('#thumbs img').each(function(){
   $(this).parent().find('ul').append('<li><a href="'+$(this).attr('src')+'"><img src="'+$(this).attr('src')+'"/></a></li>'); 
   $(this).remove();
});
```

If u wanna do this for many div in that page, then use the following code

```
$('#thumbs .thumbs').each(function(){                
   $(this).find('img').each(function(){
       $(this).parent().parent().find('ul').append('<li><a href="'+$(this).attr('src')+'"><img src="'+$(this).attr('src')+'"/></a></li>'); 
       $(this).remove();
   });
});
```

Thanks Goysar,

Comment: Hi that's great thanks. Will this empty anything which is in the div after I have pulled the images? There are `<p>` tags in there

Comment: This hasn't worked unfortunately, it has removed all the images

Comment: This code will not remove anything other than images in the div. if you dont wanna remove the images then remove the following code.
$(this).remove();
the above line is responsible for removing the images.